# Create characters like "aaa" and "baa" and so on till "zzz" in bash to a string

Tags: linux, bash, loops

Help me to create characters in bash and add to a string in a orderly manner like

```
AAA
AAB
AAC
AAD
AAE
...
ZZV
ZZW
ZZX
ZZY
ZZZ
```

Answer (score 0):

User brace expansion:

```sh
for triple in {A..Z}{A..Z}{A..Z} ; do
    string+=$triple
done
```